# Pass python session to a script written with another version of python

Tags: python, session, version

For example, if I have:

(1) ScriptA, written in 2.X as it needs 2.X libraries

(2) ScriptB, written in 3.X, as it needs 3.X libraries

Is there a way to do the following?:

-> ScriptA calls scriptB (switching Python version), passing a session object without serializing it.

Using a command line makes it possible to switch python version, but without the possibility of passing a session object...

**-- EDIT --**

By session, I mean for example that I have an opened TCP/IP connection to a given server, and I don't want to open a new one in the second script

Comment: I would try with pickle, but I'm not sure it will work...

Comment: @plaes: OP says "without serializing"

Comment: @plaes Yes, that will work as long as both python versions support the same pickle protocol version.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. By session, I mean for example that I have an opened TCP/IP connection to a given server, and I don't want to open a new one in the second script. I will check pickle but I doubt it allows to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seens what you want is possible - though I don't have how to test it with a full code, I made some testing on the terminal, and it went fine -

An open TCP/IP connection is a process resource that can be shared with a process's children and siblings.

Therefore, there is nothing preventing you from using the traditional Posix calls for starting a new process, running your python3 script, and within it, recreate the socket using only the "fileno" attribute for it.

The "fileno" is what identifies the connection at the OS level, and it is a  parameter that can be passed to the socket.socket constructor.

So, on the calling script, you do something on the lines of:

```
import os
....

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.execv("/usr/bin/python3.2", ["python3.2", path_to_python3_script, mysocket.fileno")
```

and on the python3.2 script:

```
import sys
import socket
socket_fileno = int(sys.argv[1])
mysocket = socket.socket(fileno=socket_fileno)
```

Btw, you didn't specify the OS you are working on - if you have the bad luck to use Windows, it does not use `fork`, but there should be a work around.

Comment: Hi jsbueno, thanks for the idea I will try this and see if it works. btw, I am working on windows :-)